# Finding all possible solution pairs to an algebra problem with constraints in python

Tags: python, sympy, algebra

I am trying to use python to create list of all pairs of numbers between 2 and 75 that average to 54, where each value in each solution pair can go up to 6 decimal places. And so I want to have a list of all of these solution pairs.

I have tried using `solve()` from `SymPy` to solve this as an algebra problem, but I am unsure how to handle this when the equation has many solutions, and further includes constraints. How can I approach this problem so that I account for my constraints, where all values in each solution pair need to be between 2 and 75?

Comment: Ah, we're reading it differently. If OP wants the way I read it, `((i/1000000,108-i/1000000) for i in range(33000000,75000001))` will do the trick. I'm not sure which one of us is interpreting the question correctly here.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @Mous. So I am trying to understand this code here, which I see is a list comprehension. I am guessing the "1000000" tells us we want accuracy to 6 decimal places, the 108 is because this is an average and so 54*2, but why "33000000" and "75000001"? Didn't already declare we want 6 decimal places with the "1000000"? My constraint was not 33. And when I try to run the code I just get "<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001D1CB6AE900>" and not a list of all the solution pairs. Thank you!

Comment: The 33 is just (54x2)-75, because if either of the values is less than 33 there aren't any solution pairs. With regard to the generator object comment, you need to iterate through it. I've edited my answer to show that. The 75000001 instead of 75000000 is so you include 75.000000 as the final value of the range, instead of 74.999999

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can click the green checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may observe that all the solutions are values (n,m) where 33<=n<=75 and n+m=108.

Hence given n, we may determine m, by just subtracting it from 108.

We iterate through the values of n and produce the values of m, using a generator, since the list is much too big to store in memory.

Note that there are *42 million* solution pairs.

To display them, you can iterate through them

```
decimals = 3

m = 10**decimals

solutions = ((i/m,round(108-i/m,decimals)) for i in range(33*m,75*m+1))

for solution_pair in solutions:
  a, b = solution_pair
  print(a, b)
```

Comment: Oh wow, I had no clue there were that many solutions, I did not realize at first I was handling a solution set with that scale of solutions. It makes sense that it could not be shown as a simple digestible list. It is taking far too long to generate this entire list, which seems quite understandable given 42 million solution pairs. I suppose then if I change the problem to have the solution values be within say 3 decimal places or 2 decimal places, I could actually see the end of the list, rather than millions of solution pairs? And so include 7501 for 3 decimal places and 751 for 2 decimals?

Comment: *"the list is much too big to store in memory"* - Meh, fits into 3.7 GB.

Comment: If you really want them in memory just use square brackets (i.e. `solutions = [ ... ]`).  But it'll take 4.3GiB of RAM to store them all.  A float is 24 bytes in Python and a 2-tuple is 56 bytes, so more than 104 bytes per pair.  Interesting that @KellyBundy reports less, would be interesting to know why!

Comment: I am just a bit confused about matching the decimal places. So if I wanted the solutions to be within 2 decimal places I would use `i/100/ and a range from 330 to 751? And if I wanted 1 decimal place solutions I would use i/10` and a range from 33 to 75? I am just confused seeing the range from 33000000 to 75000001 when my range would ideally just be entered by the user as from 33 to 75. But I get that we need to account for including 75 exactly as the final value of the range.

Comment: @LostinSpatialAnalysis you would just change the constants to 1000, 1000, 33000 and 75001 for 3 decimal places. I'll edit the answer to include a control for the number of decimal places.

Comment: @SamMason I asked the tuple, its `__sizeof__` said `40`. `sys.getsizeof` says 56, I guess that's correct even though I think the tuple is *not* "managed by the garbage collector." Corrected calculation: 42e6*(8+64+32) ≈ 4.4 GB.

Comment: @SamMason Oh and that's not for the simple list comp but for an optimized solution that reuses the float objects and that allocates the list size in advance so it doesn't overallocate.

Comment: This works wonderfully, thank you @Mous! Lastly I was just trying to get the solution pair where the first value is the minimum value in the entire list of solution pairs and the second value is the maximum value in the entire list of solution pairs. But I am thinking this would just be the very first solution pair, which I see from your code is 33.0 and 75.0, which do average to 54. So then to get an average of 54, the lowest value and highest value we could possibly simultaneously have for a single solution pair is 33.0 and 75.0. Does that sound correct?

Comment: That sounds absolutely correct.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This all makes sense and works so well!

Comment: @KellyBundy just had read of https://devguide.python.org/internals/garbage-collector/#optimization-delay-tracking-containers which suggests these tuples won't be managed by the GC.  interesting, never read that much into how it works and had always trusted `getsizeof`

Comment: @SamMason Ah, I didn't know about the delayed tracking. In any case, I think tuples always have the GC header stored with them, it just might not be used (after they get untracked). So `getsizeof` is probably trustworthy, and I should stop being lazy calling the `__sizeof__` methods.